# lodash debounce & ES6 class - this. is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have lodash debounce connected to an input which works well, however i cant seem to call other methods. I tried binding the search in my constructor. Here is my code:

```
  class SearchBar {
    constructor() {
      this.searchState = {
        term: '',
        loading: false,
      };
      this.$searchBar = $('.ngaire-search-form > input');

      this.onLoad();
      this.onSearch = _.debounce(this.onSearch.bind(this), 400);
    }

    onLoad() {
      this.$searchBar.on('keyup change', this.onSearch);
    }

    onSearch(e) {
      const searchTerm = e.currentTarget.value;

      if (searchTerm.length > 0) {
        console.log(searchTerm); // this works
        this.verifySearchTerm(searchTerm); // i get this is not a function
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to swap

```
  this.onLoad();
  this.onSearch = _.debounce(this.onSearch.bind(this), 400);
```

these 2 lines.

Otherwise inside `onLoad` you attach `this.onSearch` handler that is not a bound debounced function yet.